# Confusion about the Time Hierarchy Theorem and relativization

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, oracle-machines, relativization

I know that $\mathsf{P}^A = \mathsf{EXP}$ 
for any $\mathsf{EXPTIME}$-complete language $A$.

Is it true that $\mathsf{DTIME}^A(n^k) = \mathsf{EXP}$ 
for any fixed $k$ and any $\mathsf{EXPTIME}$-complete oracle $A$?
If not, what do these complexity classes equal and why?

I am just confused because then it seems to me that we would then have
$\mathsf{DTIME}^A(n^k) = \mathsf{DTIME}^A(n^j)$ for $k < j$ and 
this would contradict the fact that the Time Hierarchy Theorem holds under any oracle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is **not true** that for $A$ being $\sf EXP$-complete ${\sf DTIME}^A(n^k) = {\sf EXP}$, but you are right with ${\sf P}^A={\sf EXP}$.

Here is the reason for this. In order to make use of the oracle you have to transform your problem via a reduction. This reduction is a *polynomial* reduction. The running time of this particular reduction might need $\omega(n^k)$ steps. In this case you cannot use the oracle in the desired way.

As you already observed ${\sf DTIME}^A(n^k) \neq {\sf EXP}$ because this would imply  for all $k,j$ that ${\sf DTIME}^A(n^k)={\sf DTIME}^A(n^j)$, which cannot be true since the time hierarchy theorem relativizes.

Comment: Thanks.  I just wish that textbook writers were more explicit on how oracle Turing Machines work (or don't work) so I could have avoided this confusion in the first place.